# How do I set 14.04 to use two separate network?

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet

How do I set 14.04 use two separate network?

```
/etc/network/interfaces

auto lo

iface lo inet loopback

# purpose of eth0 is private lan 

iface eth0 inet static

address 192.168.2.44

gateway 192.168.2.1

netmask 255.255.255.0

network 192.168.2.0

broadcast 192.168.2.255

# wlan2 or wlan0

# purpose of wlanx is internet access

iface wlan2 inet static

address 192.168.1.44

gateway 192.168.1.1

netmast 255.255.255.0

network 192.168.1.0

broadcast 192.168.1.255
```

then

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 down (and up)

sudo ifconfig wlan2 down (and up)

sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

when I do ping 8.8.8.8, it says network is unreachable

Please advise.

Note: I do not have wpa_supplicant installed nor do I have /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf file.  I am thinking I need to install wpa_supplicant.

Thank you,
Bob

Comment: I think on wlan `network 192.168.1.0` you are saying this nic is for this network only. Try removing that line.

Comment: Thank you for reply, as per your suggestion, I've commented out wlan2 network 192.168.1.0, no effect, 8.8.8.8 is not pingable. wlanX is to be used for internet access, the eth0 is private lan only.

Comment: Can you ping anything on that network?

Comment: You could also try removing the gateway on the other nic `eth0`.

Comment: Also look at `route add ...`

Comment: commented out both gateway eth0 and wlan2 in the interfaces and sudo route add to the wlan2 resolved it. thank you all for assistance

Answer (score 0):

Your file is a bit busy and misses some crucial details. I suggest that you try:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# purpose of eth0 is private lan 
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.2.44
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.2.1

# wlan2 or wlan0

# purpose of wlanx is internet access
auto wlan2
iface wlan2 inet static
address 192.168.1.44
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1 8.8.8.8
wpa-ssid your_network_name
wpa-psk your_secret_key
```

Then either reboot or:

```
sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0
sudo ifdown wlan2 && sudo ifup -v wlan2
```

Comment: This worked better. Although, the sudo ifdown ifup commands failed. it stated the interface ifdown not configured for both eth0 and wlan2?

Comment: Does everything work as expected now?

Comment: yes and no. I had to comment out the gateways and add the networks and broadways in both nics to be able to ping 8.8.8.8, 192.168.2.1 and 192.168.1.1.  Thank you to all for your assistance. Much appreciated indeed.

Comment: Hello ... I am trying to auto set the route in the /etc/network/interfaces without having to command line sudo route add default gw 192.168.2.1 eth0 and sudo route add default gw 192.168.1.1 wlan2. I've added many different flavors via online research askubuntu help, unable to find a solution after command line sudo ifconfig eth0 down then up and sudo ifconfig wlan2 down then up. example is ... up ip route add -net 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.2.1 eth0 and up ip route add -net 192.168.1.0 gw 192.168.1.1 wlan2. thank you in advance for your time and assistance, much appreciated.

Comment: It should work perfectly fine with the gateway defined as I suggested. Why did you comment it out??